# Strange behavior with NSPredicate and NSDate

Tags: ios, timestamp, nsdate, nspredicate, behavior

I'm trying to filter results with NSPredicate but I have an strange behavior with NSDate in a NSPredicate.

Here is the code;

```
NSDate *auctionDate = obj[@"auctionDate"];
NSLog(@"%@", auctionDate);
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"auctionDate == %@", auctionDate];
NSLog(@"%@", predicate);
```

And this is the NSLog output;

```
2014-02-21 00:00:00 +0000
auctionDate == CAST(414633600.000000, "NSDate")
```

As you can see, every NSLog shows NSDate and NSPredicate string, but if you look more closely, NSDate and UNIX timestamp created by NSPredicate are not equal.

414633600.0 converted to date is "Mon, 21 Feb **1983** 00:00:00 GMT" that are not equal to original NSDate.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232203/how-to-store-dates-without-times-in-core-data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reference date used by `NSDate` is **1 January 2001, GMT**

not 1970.

Comment: Umm, thanks for response. But how I correct the date? "auctionDate" is fetched from Parse server.