# How to store only date without timezones and actual time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm just learning xcode and I tried to find the answer in internet, but no luck.
 My simple question: How to store only date without timezones and actual time with core data?
Currently I'm storing Date using `NSDateFormatter` and `NSDate`:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *dateT = [dateFormatter dateFromString:self.DateLabel.text];
[ItemDate setValue: dateT forKey:@"date"];
```

But if I'm using this part of code and printing stored date as Date: `2015-04-17 07:00:00 +0000`.

Basically I just want to remove this: `07:00:00 +0000` and store only `2015-04-17`

Is it possible?

Comment: use NSCalendar components

Answer (score 3):

Alex, after getting output date, you can try this code.

```
NSString *str1 = @"2015-04-17 07:00:00 +0000";
NSRange range = [str1 rangeOfString:@" "];

NSString *date = [str1 substringToIndex:range.location];
NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
    NSString *yourJSONString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSDate date]];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];;
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzzz"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:yourJSONString];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSString *output = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
    NSLog(@"%@", output);
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I'm doing now, but if you will store this value in core data with Attr type date you will get stored something like this: 2015-04-17 07:00:00 +0000

Answer (score 0):

The answer in [How to store dates without times in Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232203/how-to-store-dates-without-times-in-core-data) is an answer to your question (And some explanation of NSDate).

Comment: Thanks for the link!!! I have an idea how I will store the date: I will store full date (date+time+timezone), but I will set time to 00:00:00 and timezone +0000 or something for each date value in core data and I later if I will need perform fetching and printing out I will just trim default time and timezone. Time and timezone are not important in my app. Thank you!